catkin build not working on custom service
I'm trying to create a service in C++ following a tutorial.
I created a package using:
catkin_create_pkg gobot_test message_generation std_msgs roscpp

I also have the following files:
AddTwoInts.srv in srv folder (also AddTwoInts.h in package root folder)
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum

Also, add_two_ints_server.cpp in src folder
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <ros/package.h>


#include "gobot_test/AddTwoInts.h"
 
bool add(gobot_test::AddTwoInts::Request  &req,
          gobot_test::AddTwoInts::Response &res)
 {
   res.sum = req.a + req.b;
   ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b);
   ROS_INFO("sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum);
   return true;
 }
 
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_ints_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
 
   ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", add);
   ROS_INFO("Ready to add two ints.");
   ros::spin();
 
   return 0;
 }

This is a typical example. Files cmake and package are configured...
If use catkin build show this:
Errors     << gobot_test:make /home/robot/catkin_ws/logs/gobot_test/build.make.011.log                      
/home/robot/catkin_ws/src/robot_packages/gobot/gobot_test/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp:6:10: fatal error: gobot_test/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "gobot_test/AddTwoInts.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_server.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_server.dir/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:169: CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
cd /home/robot/catkin_ws/build/gobot_test; catkin build --get-env gobot_test | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-auth=3,4; cd -

I can't use catkin_make, in other occasions with catkin_make it has worked correctly, but not with catkin build
Any idea?

Sorry for delay, this is cmake file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(gobot_test)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a exec_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(DIRECTORY srv
   FILES
   AddTwoNumbers.srv
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
 )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  DEPENDS message_runtime
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/gobot_test.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/gobot_test_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables for installation
## See http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_executables.html
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark libraries for installation
## See http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_libraries.html
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_gobot_test.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)


add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)


Can you change these lines on your CMakeList?
Old version
add_service_files(DIRECTORY srv
                  FILES
                  AddTwoNumbers.srv
                 )

New version
add_service_files(
    FILES
    AddTwoInts.srv
)

Normally, ROS can detect your srv folder and your service name is different from your code. You are trying to include AddTwoInts.h but on your CMake, you have created AddTwoNumbers.srv. I think it will resolve your problem. Please give feedback after these steps.
